# Wordpress on Apache - big error.log file

Tags: wordpress, apache, logging

I have an error.log file that is over 100gb on a wordpress site. This is a legacy site that will be getting rebuilt soon enough. In the meantime is there a way to stop this filling up so rapidly?

I can't even open the file because it is so big but I assume it is just lots of php warnings and notices.

Comment: You can use `define('WP_DEBUG', false)` and `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false)` in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Thanks WP_DEBUG was already false but WP_DEBUG_LOG was not set.

Comment: I think maybe setting the apache log to a lot lower level https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: Comment out `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` in your host config file.